# Can you have an alias for a subdomain with a ssl cert

Tags: ssl, https, cross-domain, iis-7.5, subdomain

I have a wildcard certificate for our domain.   `*.domain.com`

We host multiple sites on our one server using host headers with subdomains. In this specific case lets use `site1.domain.com` the site has a https binding on the hostname with the wildcard ssl cert.

for marketing reasons we want to rename the sites URL / Name. for example `awesomewebsite.com`

But for hosting and ssl certificate reasons we cant simply change the host headers on the site.

So my question. Is there a way for me to make `awesomewebsite.com` an alias to`https://site1.domain.com` so that the user can operate and use the site as if it was hosted at `awesomewebsite.com` and for security reasons all requests are actually sent to `https://site1.domain.com`

I have both the domains with 'dyndns.org' I know they offer some added services. Not sure if that will be of any user to me?

Also if I can obtain this are there any security concerns or other  issues which might be introduced.

When using webhop feature in dyndns.org i get the following error:

`Refused to display 'https://site1.domain.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'`

Answer (score 0):

> So my question. Is there a way for me to make awesomewebsite.com an alias tohttps://site1.domain.com so that the user can operate and use the site as if it was hosted at awesomewebsite.com and for security reasons all requests are actually sent to https://site1.domain.com

The validation of the contents of the certificate is done against the name in the URL, which means that your certificate must contain the alias name too.

Comment: So you are saying I must add `awesomewebsite.com` to the ssl cert. And then add in my iss settings for the site a host name for both `awesomewebsite.com` and `site1.domain.com`

Comment: I have been playing with the dyndns services and I found the following feature:  `Webhop` which points `awesomesite.com` to `https://site1.domain.com` and it seems to work when I go to `awesomewebsite.com` however I am getting this error:  `Refused to display 'https://site1.domain.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do and what this has to do with the original question.  I assume that you are using the [cloaking](http://www.dyndns.com/services/webredirect/readme.html) feature which will not work with sites why deny to get put into an (i)frame. But this is has nothing to do with SSL.

Comment: it has to do with my ssl cert only being valid for my subdomain names. Buying annother ssl cert for my domain is not an option. I have to make use of the wildcard ssl cert. But I need the site to work with my domain name.

Comment: Again: https  will not work if the name does not match. What you are trying now is using http (without SSL) to put the SSL site into a frame. This will not magically make the non-SSL site to SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Never answered properly.

For whom  who ends up here during a search:

What you need is a certificate (requested) with alternative names, meaning it contains all the variances you desire of FQDN/DNS names. They do  not need to match or belong to the same domain. Also ideal for external name and system internal names (e.g. [www.mystuff.com](http://www.mystuff.com), host123.myhost.com):

https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm